# How do I target 2nd and 3rd elements with nth-child using just one line of css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to target the 2nd and 3rd elements in my div using nth-child but I only want to use one line of css instead of two.

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use the nth-child selector to target both?

Answer (score 8):

You can specifically target each `p` tag by its `nth-child` and separate with a comma.

Or you can reduce selectors by specifying a range like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/304tacrk/2/)

```
p:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)  { color: red; }
```

Comment: This was the answer I was after. Wasn't sure how to use the math of the nth-child to target. Now I've learnt you can combine two and specify a range. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the comma operator to combine two selectors:

```
p:nth-child(2), p:nth-child(3) { color: red; }
```

Another approach that might be less cryptic (depending on the application) is to use a class for the highlighted paragraphs:

```
<div>
    <p>One</p>
    <p class="important">Two</p>
    <p class="important">Three</p>
    <p>Four</p>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
p.important { color: red; }
```

Or, if what you really want to do is style the first and last paragraphs differently from the interior paragraphs, you can do that explicitly:

```
p:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) { color: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful. I should have clarified that I was trying to just use one line including nth-child. Still learnt a lot. Cheers.